# parsing log with grok but with varying line formats in nodejs

Tags: node.js, logging, logstash-grok

I'm trying to parse some logs with grok but am having some trouble doing it when the log lines don't look the same sometimes...

My log file lets say looks like this:

```
[2017-02-03 19:15:51,112] INFO [Group Metadata Manager on Broker 1]: Removed 0 expired offsets in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataManager)
[2017-02-03 19:25:51,112] INFO [Group Metadata Manager on Broker 1]: Removed 0 expired offsets in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataManager)
[2017-02-03 19:26:20,605] INFO Rolled new log segment for \'omega-replica-sync-dev-8\' in 21 ms. (kafka.log.Log)
[2017-02-03 19:26:20,605] INFO Scheduling log segment 1 for log omega-replica-sync-dev-8 for deletion. (kafka.log.Log)
[2017-02-03 19:27:20,606] INFO Deleting segment 1 from log omega-replica-sync-dev-8. (kafka.log.Log)
```

My current node code looks like this:

```
'use strict';

var nodegrok = require('node-grok');
var Regex = require("regex");
var zlib = require('zlib');

var msg = '[2017-02-03 19:15:51,112] INFO [Group Metadata Manager on Broker 1]: Removed 0 expired offsets in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataManager)\n[2017-02-03 19:25:51,112] INFO [Group Metadata Manager on Broker 1]: Removed 0 expired offsets in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataManager)\n[2017-02-03 19:26:20,605] INFO Rolled new log segment for \'omega-replica-sync-dev-8\' in 21 ms. (kafka.log.Log)\n[2017-02-03 19:26:20,605] INFO Scheduling log segment 1 for log omega-replica-sync-dev-8 for deletion. (kafka.log.Log)\n[2017-02-03 19:27:20,606] INFO Deleting segment 1 from log omega-replica-sync-dev-8. (kafka.log.Log)'

console.log('message: ', msg);

var p2 = '\\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\\] %{LOGLEVEL:level} \\[%{DATA:message1}\\]: %{GREEDYDATA:message2}'

var lines = msg.toString().split('\n');

for(var i = 0;i < lines.length;i++){

    console.log('line [i]:', lines[i])
    var str = lines[i]

    var patterns = require('node-grok').loadDefaultSync();
    var pattern = patterns.createPattern(p2)
    console.log('pattern:', pattern.parseSync(lines[i]));

}
```

but the last two seem to output null...since its missing the 3rd part in the pattern.

```
line [i]: [2017-02-03 19:15:51,112] INFO [Group Metadata Manager on Broker 1]: Removed 0 expired offsets in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataManager)
pattern: { timestamp: '2017-02-03 19:15:51,112',
  level: 'INFO',
  message1: 'Group Metadata Manager on Broker 1',
  message2: 'Removed 0 expired offsets in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataManager)' }
line [i]: [2017-02-03 19:25:51,112] INFO [Group Metadata Manager on Broker 1]: Removed 0 expired offsets in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataManager)
pattern: { timestamp: '2017-02-03 19:25:51,112',
  level: 'INFO',
  message1: 'Group Metadata Manager on Broker 1',
  message2: 'Removed 0 expired offsets in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataManager)' }
line [i]: [2017-02-03 19:26:20,605] INFO Rolled new log segment for 'omega-replica-sync-dev-8' in 21 ms. (kafka.log.Log)
pattern: null
line [i]: [2017-02-03 19:26:20,605] INFO Scheduling log segment 1 for log omega-replica-sync-dev-8 for deletion. (kafka.log.Log)
pattern: null
line [i]: [2017-02-03 19:27:20,606] INFO Deleting segment 1 from log omega-replica-sync-dev-8. (kafka.log.Log)
pattern: null
```

How can you format lines with varying formats then in grok?

Answer (score 0):

so here is one way of doing it that I got to work...essentially looking to see if the pattern matches with an if statement and then evaluating but, what if there are 6 potential formats of the log? Do I have to right 6 if statements that are nested then? Does sound like an efficient way to me...is there a better way?

```
'use strict';

var nodegrok = require('node-grok');
var Regex = require("regex");
var zlib = require('zlib');

var msg = '[2017-02-03 19:15:51,112] INFO [Group Metadata Manager on Broker 1]: Removed 0 expired offsets in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataManager)\n[2017-02-03 19:25:51,112] INFO [Group Metadata Manager on Broker 1]: Removed 0 expired offsets in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataManager)\n[2017-02-03 19:26:20,605] INFO Rolled new log segment for \'omega-replica-sync-dev-8\' in 21 ms. (kafka.log.Log)\n[2017-02-03 19:26:20,605] INFO Scheduling log segment 1 for log omega-replica-sync-dev-8 for deletion. (kafka.log.Log)\n[2017-02-03 19:27:20,606] INFO Deleting segment 1 from log omega-replica-sync-dev-8. (kafka.log.Log)'

console.log('message: ', msg);

var p2 = '\\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\\] %{LOGLEVEL:level} \\[%{DATA:message1}\\]: %{GREEDYDATA:message2}'

var lines = msg.toString().split('\n');

for(var i = 0;i < lines.length;i++){

    console.log('line [i]:', lines[i])
    var str = lines[i]
    var p = '\\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\\] %{LOGLEVEL:level} \\[%{DATA:message1}\\]: %{GREEDYDATA:message2}'
    var p2 = '\\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\\] %{LOGLEVEL:level} %{GREEDYDATA:message2}'

    var patterns = require('node-grok').loadDefaultSync();
    var pattern = patterns.createPattern(p)

    if (pattern.parseSync(lines[i]) == null ) {
        var pattern = patterns.createPattern(p2)
        console.log('patternf:', pattern.parseSync(lines[i]));

    } else {
        console.log('pattern:', pattern.parseSync(lines[i]));   
    }

}
```